# Hook into password change on user update

Tags: 8, users, hooks

**Question in short:** How do I hook into password change in order to get plaintext old and plaintext new password when password change is accepted?

**What I have tried so far:** I tried hook_form_alter with

```
$form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()
```

but this gets me only a hashed password.

**What I want to do / context:** I use the user's password to encrypt and decrypt some (very few) field values which I don't want to have plain text saved. User has to enter his account password in a custom form to decrypt/view a value.

When a user changes his password, the encrypted values should be automatically updated: decrypted with the old password, encrypted with the new one.

(I'm aware of the fact that these encrypted values are lost when user forgets his password and uses password reset.)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the plain text password anywhere. That violates everything about modern site security. Is there a reason you can't use a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/field_encrypt?

Comment: It occurs to me that you aren't saving the password, just using it.

Comment: Of course you are right to never ever store plain text passwords. Like you added I never planned to save these passwords. I just have to work with them on the fly before they are hashed. And yes, sadly there are reasons I can't use field_encrypt (based on encrypt based on key). Reasons besides that it's alpha / rc state and like I think does not support a key provider based on the user's account passphrase.

Comment: Have you thought about using the encrypt module to handle encryption, then using the user auth service to validate the user's attempt to decrypt the data?

Comment: I want the application/environment to not know (plain-save) the user-specific encryption/decryption passphrase. The account passwords are already in place and securely hashed. With some extended password policy they should do the job.

Comment: It seems like you're working on something well defined and with a specific purpose, but I would encourage you to rethink the system for the following reasons. 1. If the data is encrypted on the site when the user submits it, and is only visible to the user, why should the site store that information at all? 2. Passwords aren't strong encryption keys and can be brute forced. 3. Any data worth securing is worth using industry best practices to secure. I'm not suggesting the encrypt module simply because it's easier to use a contrib module than a homebrew.